# Adding values from one data set to the ggplots (with several variables)

Tags: r, ggplot2

By using this function, I can add outliers values into the plot of mpg

```
outlier_values. <- lapply(mtcars[-c(8,9)], function(x){outlier_values <- boxplot.stats(x)$out})
boxplot(mtcars$mpg, main="Pressure Height", boxwex=0.1)
mtext(paste("Outliers: ", paste(outlier_values., collapse=", ")), cex=0.6)
```

Buy now I want to add the outlier values `(outlier1)` to the plot of all variables:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

outlier <- do.call("cbind", lapply(mtcars[-c(8,9)], function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$out))
outlier1 <- melt(outlier)

mtcars_m = melt(mtcars[,-c(8,9)])
names(mtcars_m)=c("X2","CI")
box.plot<- ggplot(mtcars_m, aes(X2, CI,fill=Models)) +
 geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) +
 facet_wrap(~ Models, scales = "free") +
 guides(fill=FALSE) + 
 labs(x="", y="") +
 ggtitle("Box Plots")
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some variables which are undefined (`Models`). I assume you meant `X2`. Here is the `ggplot2` solution:

```
outlier1 <- melt(data.frame(outlier))
colnames(mtcars_m) <- colnames(outlier1) <- c("X2","CI")
mtcars_m$Outlier <- FALSE
outlier1$Outlier <- TRUE

ggData <- rbind(mtcars_m, outlier1) 

ggplot(ggData, aes(x=X2, y=CI, fill=X2) ) +
 geom_boxplot() + 
 geom_point(aes(colour=Outlier)) + 
  labs(x="",y="") +
  ggtitle("Box Plots") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
 facet_wrap(~ X2, scales = "free")
```